# Moving AnyLogic agents according to database table

Tags: anylogic

My model has a collection of trucks, where the Source block provides each truck with a unique ID. I also have a database containing information on the vehicles' movements.

[image: Movement Information]

No column has unique values, but together the `trip_start_date` and `vehicle_id` should be a unique set. I'm trying to structure a moveTo block such that when a date in the `trip_start_time` column is reached during the model runtime, then the agent with that `vehicle_id` as a parameter will move to the lat/long in a certain amount of time.

[image: Structure of latitude argument (longitude and trip time are similar)]

However, I'm getting an "empty database value result." I'm wondering if this is because it's expecting every model date to have an entry? I considered making a function that's called when a date in the database is encountered, but I was told that the moveTo block should be able to handle this activity. Help in resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The way you are trying to use the MoveTo block is not correct. It is hard to explain here but I think you need to go through a few tutorials inside help to get a better fundamental understanding.

However, below is a reproducible example of the behavior I think you want to implement, but using agent-based approach instead of a process-centric or discrete event approach.

I have an agent called Vehicle with a ID called vehicle ID.

There is a Dynamic event has all the parameters found in the DB

[image]

Then at the start of the model, we generate all the moveTo events found in the Database using the code below.

```
List<Tuple> rows = selectFrom(db_table)
    .where(db_table.vehicle_id.eq(vehicleID))
    .list();

for (Tuple row : rows) {
    //What is the start time of the movement
    double timeToTripBegin = dateToTime(row.get( db_table.trip_begin_time ));
    //Lets create a new movement event to trigger the movement int he future
    create_MoveToLocation(timeToTripBegin, 
        row.get( db_table.latitude ), 
        row.get( db_table.longitude ), 
        row.get( db_table.trip_duration_h ));
}
```

This event will then execute the move to when the time arrives